# Plotting time from POSIXct object on axis using ggplot2

Tags: datetime, ggplot2, label, axis, posixct

I have a data frame `splineset` of a spline interpolation (x and y values) based on some time dependent data, `df`. `df` has columns `df$value` and `df$time`, where `time` is a POSIXct datetime object and `value` is a numeric.

`splineset` was created with `splineset <- as.data.frame(spline(df$time, df$value))`

I'm plotting it with code:

```
base <- ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_line(data = splineset, aes(x = x, y = y))

base
```

I want to plot the spline interpolation with the `df` scatterplot, but my plot x-axis shows the numeric POSIXct value (seconds since 1970-01-01) instead of the date. If I convert `splineset$x <- as.Date(splineset$x)`and try to plot it, I get the error:

`Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Any advice? I want my axis to display the date properly, and can't figure out a way to do it. The error is unhelpful since it seems I already converted it to a Date class.

Thanks

Edit: output of `dput(head(splineset,20))`:

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(1420261200, 1420294782.72251, 
1420328365.44503, 1420361948.16754, 1420395530.89005, 1420429113.61257, 
1420462696.33508, 1420496279.05759, 1420529861.7801, 1420563444.50262, 
1420597027.22513, 1420630609.94764, 1420664192.67016, 1420697775.39267, 
1420731358.11518, 1420764940.8377, 1420798523.56021, 1420832106.28272, 
1420865689.00524, 1420899271.72775), class = "Date"), y = c(4748.5, 
4212.52512190184, 5425.53465349697, 7799.44656819583, 10683.9379760372, 
13353.4154924385, 15152.5922945744, 15891.6831978947, 15561.4833407268, 
14317.8145462586, 12609.7380342676, 10887.8275183587, 9315.03076879911, 
7888.68545478638, 6604.14143895759, 5456.74858394579, 4441.85675236009, 
3554.81580684035, 2790.97560999938, 2145.68602447347), x.time = structure(c(1420261200, 
1420294782.72251, 1420328365.44503, 1420361948.16754, 1420395530.89005, 
1420429113.61257, 1420462696.33508, 1420496279.05759, 1420529861.7801, 
1420563444.50262, 1420597027.22513, 1420630609.94764, 1420664192.67016, 
1420697775.39267, 1420731358.11518, 1420764940.8377, 1420798523.56021, 
1420832106.28272, 1420865689.00524, 1420899271.72775), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Indianapolis")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi. Does the problem still persist? Please help us help you and post the output of `dput(head(splineset,20))` into the question, please also select only the columns that are actually used for the plot.  your current plot is plotting `df` in `geom_point`, not sure if that is intended.

Comment: It's intended, I want to show the raw data and the spline interpolation on the same plot!

Comment: your data frame contains `x`, as date class in weird formatting and `x.time`, which seems to me the column that you want to plot  (this is in POSIXct). `ggplot() +
        geom_line(data = splineset, aes(x = x.time, y = y))` works and gives a good graph with dates in the x axis. You should be able to plot variables from `df` on it, if the x is indeed also POSIX